# grunt not installing properly for the commands

Tags: gruntjs

[image]

The cursor is continuously rotating for the longer time. i have tried with

`sudo npm install -g grunt-cli`  and `npm install -g grunt-cli`

but both of them are not working. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using proxy server in your environment? 
If so, you need to exec the command below to make npm use proxy server

npm config set proxy http://proxy-url:port

Comment: Yes, or you can create .npmrc file under this path ~/.npmrc and write "proxy = http://proxy.example.com:8080"into the file

Comment: has your probrem been solved? please share the result with us!